# Touchegg keyboard shortcuts ignored by Gnome

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension, workspace-switcher, touchegg

I have [touchegg](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg) setup to use touchpad gestures, and I'm also using the [Gnome Workspace Matrix extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1485/workspace-matrix/) to use 2D layout of workspaces. I'm trying to use a gesture to switch between workspaces by having touchegg send keyboard shortcuts (Control, Alt, and an arrow key), but Gnome is ignoring them. Something odd I'm noticing is that when I use the gesture all the keys show up in `xev`, but when I physically press the key combination to change workspaces, I'll only see Control & Alt show up, but then none the arrow keys.

I was wondering if anyone knows if there's some other key I should be having touchegg send instead of the regular arrow keys, or if there's something causing Gnome to specifically ignore the keystrokes coming from touchegg?

Answer (score 0):

The below configuration worked for me:

```
<gesture type="SWIPE" fingers="4" direction="RIGHT">
    <action type="SEND_KEYS">
        <repeat>false</repeat>
        <modifiers>Control_L</modifiers>
        <keys>Alt_L+Left</keys>
        <on>begin</on>
    </action>
</gesture>
```